# show more than 50 items on selection on admin ui

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

I have created 56 categories and when i am trying to create a new post when i am going to select the category that i want there are only 50.The other 6 doesn't appear and you cant select them even by typing the name of the category its like it doesn't exist.
How can i fix that?
Here is the models

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
 * Post Model
 * ==========
 */

var Post = new keystone.List('Post', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },
});

Post.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    categories: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'PostCategory', many: true},// <- This is Shows only 50 instead of 56!
    state: { type: Types.Select, options: 'draft, published, archived', default: 'published', index: true, required: true },
    publishedDate: { type: Types.Date, index: true, default: Date.now, required: true, dependsOn: { state: 'published' } },
    mainPDF: { type: Types.LocalFile,   dest: 'public/pdf/mainpdf'},
    pronunciations: { type: Types.LocalFile, dest: 'public/pdf/pronunciations'},
    answers: { type: Types.LocalFile,   dest: 'public/pdf/answers' },
 }}
    });

Post.schema.virtual('content.full').get(function () {
    return this.content.extended || this.content.brief;
});
Post.defaultColumns = 'title,categories|20%, publishedDate|20%';
Post.register();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `/node_modules/keystone/admin/api/list.js` file, and comment out the first three lines under the `case: 'autocomplete'` line (around line 26). This only works for Keystone 3; I don't know if this is an issue or Keystone 4, or how to solve it if it is (this file is in a different location and I haven't found it.) The new code should look like this:

```
case 'autocomplete':
    // var limit = Number(req.query.limit) || 50;
    // var page = Number(req.query.page) || 1;
    // var skip = limit * (page - 1);
```

I don't think this is possible if you're managing Keystone online (Heroku, Digital Ocean, Amazon S3) if it downloads from your `package.json` unless you create a fork of Keystone 3 and host that on NPM.

Comment: well when i comment the lines it was crashing but i changed the limit to 100 now its fine thnx for the help